How does this definition of the slices of a map on a product space make sense?

I'm a student studying general topology now; This is my teacher's lecture note. I'm confused with the definition of the slice. How does the inclusion (60) $\iota$ work from $p_i$ to $p$, is $p$  a point of the product space?

I suspect there is no one more qualified than your teacher to clarify their lecture notes.

I think your teacher mixed up an $i$ and a $j$ in equation (60). But even accounting for that, it may still be hard to see what is meant due to the different indices and objects used.
In words, let's say I have a product space $X \times Y \times Z$ and I label the coordinates 1 (for $X$), 2 (for $Y$) and 3 (for $Z$). I first choose one of the three coordinate indices of this product space, say $i = 2$, which corresponds to the space $Y$. I then select one point $p_{\hat{2}} = (x, z)$ in the product $X \times Z$ of the other spaces.
The slice at $p_{\hat{2}}$ is now $\{x\} \times Y \times \{z\}$. All coordinates are kept fixed except for the $i$-th coordinate.
In the general case, I have the space $\prod_{j \in I} X_j$ and choose some $i \in I$ and some $p_{\hat{\imath}} = (p_j)_{j \in I  \setminus \{i\}} \in \prod_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}} X_j$. Let's say $I = \{1, 2, \dots, k\}$ for ease of writing. The inclusion map the teacher is referring to would be
$$
\iota_{p_{\hat{\imath}}}: X_i \to \prod_{j \in I} X_j, q \mapsto (p_1, p_2, \dots, p_{i-1}, q, p_{i+1}, \dots, p_{k-1}, p_k).
$$
The slice at $p_{\hat{\imath}}$ is the image (i.e. range) of $\iota_{p_{\hat{\imath}}}$, which is
$$
\{p_1\} \times \{p_2\} \times \dots \times \{p_{i-1}\} \times X_i \times \{p_{i+1}\} \times \dots \times \{p_{k-1}\} \times \{p_k\}.
$$

As a side note, the notation $p_{\hat{\imath}} \times X_i$ for ${p_1} \times \dots \times {p_{i-1}} \times X \times {p_{i+1}} \times \dots \times {p_k}$ is used quite a lot in disciplines where arbitrary coordinate functions appear, like the study of manifolds. The convenience and space-efficiency win out over the loss of clarity and potential for misinterpretation.

What a wonderful,neat and concise explanation !  Thank you for your typing so many words.

There's something very imprecise about this definition. What the author wanted to say is
$$\iota_{(p_i)}(x)_j=\begin{cases}
p_j&\text{if }j\neq i\\
x&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
The definition makes sense becase $(p_j)$ is defined everywhere except for $i$, while $x\in X_i$.
It looks like the author tried to use some short notation, but honestly, it doesn't make much sense to me.

@EdwardH the "$p_i$" symbol is already used as underscript in $\iota$. That's one error. Moreover $p_i$ notation literally means "$i$-th element of $(p_i)$ collection" which is not defined. Next $(p_j)_{j\in J}$ is not defined, unless it already is defined by $\iota$ that I defined. This is an extreme abuse of notation and circular references.

@EdwardH fair enough, I missed this tiny hat. It deosn't matter. The $p_i$ is still abuse of notation, since there is no $i$-th element of $(p_i)$ collection. And $(p_j)_{j\in J}$ is circular, you cannot define it without $\iota$.

@EdwardH yes, that's literally what I wrote in my answer, but in sane, human readable way. Without weird notations and circular references.

@EdwardH of course not. The "$p=(p_j)_{j\in J}$" bit is either abuse of notation or circular reference or both.

@EdwardH because $(p_j)_{j\in J}$ is literally defined as $\iota(p_i)$. You can say "it is a collection such that $j$-th element is the already existing $p_j$ when $i\neq j$ and $p_i$ argument otherwise" but that is literally the definition of $\iota(p_i)$, just written in words. Don't you see it? In other words, you cannot define any of those symbols in terms of the other. Their the same thing. It's like writing $x=x$.

@EdwardH In what world $tx$ is defined through $f_t(x)$? No, it is not similar at all. If you don't see it, then I encourage you to formally define $(p_j){j\in J}$ given $(p_j){j\in J\backslash{i}}$ and some $p_i$. The only way is to use $\iota$ or equivalent. These are just different symbols for the same thing.

@EdwardH it doesn't matter what notation you use. You keep writing the same thing. Yes, you can define $(p_j){j\in J}$ like this. But it is literally the same definition for $\iota$. In other words: yes, this can serve as definition for both. But definining $\iota$ in terms of $(p_j){j\in J}$ or vice versa is meaningless without this crucial addition. As I said: either abuse of notation and laziness, or circular reference.

@EdwardH the example of $tx$ that you keep recalling is completely unrelated to this problem. The proper analogy is defining $f_t(x)=g_t(x)$, without defining/constructing $g_t(x)$. It is up to the reader to guess what "$g_t(x)$" notation means, even though you could define $f_t(x)=tx$, in a straight forward manner. Not to mention multiple abuses of notation. Which is not uncommon to academic teachers. Anyway, I'm done with discussing this further.

Examine this inclusion on a simple example.  For example, take
$$
X_1 = \{1, 2, 3\}, \quad X_2 = \{4, 5, 6\}, \quad X_3 = \{7, 8, 9\},
$$
all with discrete topology, and, say, let $i = 1$.  Now write down the inclusion explicitly.

I'm still confused,because I don't know what the $(p_j)_j \in I$ is ? Is a point of the product?
